# Mostrar filas de matriz

Tags: java

Tengo que construir una matriz y mostrar sus dos últimas filas con todos sus elementos.  Entiendo que la manera mas tradicional de hacerlo es algo así (aclaro que la variable "filas" fue cargada por teclado anteriormente al preguntar cuantas filas y columnas tendría la matriz):

```
public void mostrarDosUltimasF() {

        System.out.println("fila ante ultima.................");
        for (int x = 0; x < mat[filas -1].length; x++) {
            System.out.println(mat[filas - 2][x]);
        }
        System.out.println("Fila ultima............");
        for (int x = 0; x < mat[filas-1].length; x++) {
            System.out.println(mat[filas - 1][x]);
        }
```

la duda que yo tengo y que no entiendo, es por qué debo poner el -1 en ambos for. En el tutorial dice que al existir siempre el espacio [0][0], sin ese -1 se daría el error "out of bounds". Es lo que me pasó a mi cuando intenté hacerlo por mi cuenta. Pero sigo sin entender bien el motivo ya que si el valor de "filas" fuese por ejemplo 3, al arrancar la x del for  en 0, bastaría con tres reproducciones. Mientras que mi lógica me decía que poniendo el -1, el for sólo se reproduciría dos veces ya que el valor quedaría en 2. Todo funciona bien ahora pero hay algo que estoy entendiendo mal.  Muchas gracias.

Comment: Revisa los datos que estás usando. Ya tienes la respuesta tú mismo: nos dijiste que `filas` se carga por teclado cuando el usuario dice cuántas filas quiere. Digamos que quiere 3. Si tu matriz tiene tres filas y tres columnas, cuál es el primer índice? Teniendo eso en cuenta, cuál es el último?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagina que tienes esta matriz:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Si le ponemos posiciones vendria a ser de la siguiente forma:

```
[00, 01, 02]
[10, 11, 12]
[20, 21, 22]
```

donde `filas` es igual a `3`, tu `for` tiene lo siguiente

```
for (int x = 0; x < mat[filas - 1].length; x++)
```

lo que seria igual a:

```
for (int x = 0; x < mat[3 - 1].length; x++)
```

Ahora bien si volvemos a la matriz tenemos que `mat[3 - 1]` o `mat[2]` es la ultima fila:

```
[00, 01, 02]
[10, 11, 12]
[20, 21, 22]  <=  Exactamente aqui esta la fila 2
```

Que en tu matriz con datos seria:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]  <=  Esta es la fila 2
```

y si continuamos reemplazando tendrias lo siguiente:

```
for (int x = 0; x < [7, 8, 9].length; x++)
```

Lo que al final seria:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
```

Lo que te ayudaria a recorrer los tres valores que tienes en esa fila, ahora bien si tuvieras:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 1, 2, 3]
```

Al realizar el `length - 1` del `for` tendrias:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
```

y asi se asegura que cualquiera sea la dimension de la fila siempre te correra ese codigo.

Espero se entienda mi explicacion ;) Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Los arreglos unidimensionales comienzan a contarse desde 0, es decir, si nosostros tenemos el siguiente código:

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
for(int i = 0; i != arr.length; ++i)
{
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Si te das cuenta, estoy creando un arreglo de 5 elementos, sin embargo, para poder acceder a cada dato del arreglo, se empieza desde la posición `0`. Esto gráficamente se vería de esta forma:

```
Posición:      0    1    2    3    4
Arreglo:      |0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0|
```

Entonces, el bucle for de arriba seguirá haciendo 5 iteraciones y por ende, imprimirá los datos del arreglo sin ningún problema. Pero esto se debe, porqué las posiciones del arreglo comienza desde `0` y termina en la posición `N-1` (donde `N` es el tamaño de elementos del arreglo).

Ahora, entendiendo esto, podemos contestar rápidamente a tu duda:

> > la duda que yo tengo y que no entiendo, es por qué debo poner el -1 en ambos for. En el tutorial dice que al existir siempre el espacio [0][0], sin ese -1 se daría el error "out of bounds".

```
for (int x = 0; x < mat[filas -1].length; x++) 
    System.out.println(mat[filas - 2][x]);
```

Asumamos que tenemos una matriz de `5x6` (`5` filas y `6` columnas). Entonces, este código, debería dar como resultado un `6`(porqué son `6` columnas):

```
mat[filas -1].length
```

Sin embargo, la razón principal del porqué necesitas restarle `-1`, es porqué las posiciones de cada fila se comienza a contar desde `0` y termina en `N-1`.

En nuestro ejemplo es válido hacer esto:

```
int len1 = mat[0].length;//Dará como resultado 6
int len2 = mat[1].length;//Dará como resultado 6
int len3 = mat[2].length;//Dará como resultado 6
int len4 = mat[3].length;//Dará como resultado 6
int len5 = mat[4].length;//Dará como resultado 6
//Siempre dará el mismo resultado.
```

Los resultados que guardamos en cada variable, es el tamaño de columnas de la matriz, pero para poder lograrlo, debemos empezar con el índice `0` y terminar en el `4`.

Si hiciéramos esto:

```
int len5 = mat[5].length;
```

Nos daría la siguiente excepción: [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html), pero esto pasó,
porqué el índice `5` no es válido, no es algo que debemos hacer, porqué el índice máximo debe ser 4 (en este caso claro), de lo contrario, estamos intentando [desbordar el búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer) y obviamente, la máquina virtual de Java nunca dejará que esto pase y por esa razón tu programa dejaría de funcionar.

Ahora, luego dices lo siguiente:

> > Pero sigo sin entender bien el motivo ya que si el valor de "filas" fuese por ejemplo 3, al arrancar la x del for en 0, bastaría con tres reproducciones. Mientras que mi lógica me decía que poniendo el -1, el for sólo se reproduciría dos veces ya que el valor quedaría en 2. Todo funciona bien ahora pero hay algo que estoy entendiendo mal. Muchas gracias.

Asumamos que la matriz `3x3` fue construida de esta forma:

```
p2:  0    1   2 
0   |23  24  25|
1   |26  27  28|
2   |29  30  31|
p1:
```

Vamos asumir que p2 representa los índices de las columnas y p1 el índice de cada fila.

A simple vista, si vemos el siguiente código:

```
for (int x = 0; x < mat[filas -1].length; x++)
```

Nos daría como resultado un `3`. La variable `x` debe iterar la posición `0`, `1`, `2` para mostrar los elementos de la matriz, pero date cuenta, he realizado 3 iteraciones, es decir, ya recorrí 3 columnas de X fila empezando desde 0 y terminando en `N-1`.

No te puede dar como resultado un `2`, porqué el tamaño de la columna será un `3` en este caso.

E incluso, podría también hacerlo de esta forma (aún así, seguirá haciendo 3 iteraciones):

```
for (int x = 0; x < mat[0].length; x++)
```

Y de este modo, no necesitas restarle `-1`, esto se lo hace porqué los índices no puede sobrepasarse de `2` (en este caso es `2` porqué el tamaño máximo de columnas es `3`).